# Php максимальный элемент в массиве?

Tags: php

есть массив

```
    array(10) {  
    [4]=>  //ключ
    array(1) {     
    ["val"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "10000"
    }
  }
  [3]=>   //ключ
  array(1) {
    ["val"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "351"
    }
  }
  [5]=>  //ключ
  array(1) {
    ["val"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "100"
    }
  }
```

интересует как узнать максимальный ключ

пробовал через

```
$cnt = array_search(max($Ids),$Ids);
```

но работает через раз

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не то, чтобы что-то понятно было, но можно так:

```
$maxKey = max(array_keys($array));
```